# Reading character style and direct formatting of a MS Word character run

Tags: apache-poi

Reading a MS Word document with the Apache POI library, if a character run has a bold character style which has been overridden with direct formatting so that the character run is no longer bold, the following returns `true` when I would expect it to be `false`:

```
org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.CharacterRun characterRun;
characterRun.isBold();
```

Is there a way to get the *bold* status of a character run that takes into account both character styles and direct formatting?

Comment: POI library will give true on isBold() method on spaces. Have you considered that?